# How to dispatch a custom event in Iframe from a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have `addEventListener` and `dispatchEvent` in the same file as seen below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    addEventListener("hello", function(event) {
        console.log( event.detail.name);
    });

    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("hello", {
        detail: { name: "Patrick" }
    }));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine, but my goal is to split these two into separate files. The `addEventListener` would be located in an external file and loaded via Iframe and `dispatchEvent` would be sent from the main file.

How can I dispatch events in Iframes from the parent?

Comment: You can't dispatch events to files, you've a live document opened on a browser, and that's where you dispatch the events. If the document in the iframe is not cross-domain, you've to get a reference to the iframe showing the document, and inside the iframe there's `contentWindow`, which of `dispatch` method you're supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else is still looking for an answer, I figured out that you can just call functions from the Iframe by using:

```
frames[0].myFunction();
```

So technically you can just create a new function inside the Iframe, e.g. myFunction, and use it to dispatch the event.